# SSMS Designer Issue IIF SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I built a SQL query in SQL Server 2017 which looks like this:

```
SELECT IIF(500 < 1000, 'YES', 'NO');
```

While this works in a normal query, I cannot seem to use it in a SQL Server view. It throws an error that '<' is not recognized. The same is for all other operators.
Why can't I use it inside a view?

**Edit**

```
CREATE VIEW queryTest 
AS
    SELECT IIF(500 < 1000, 'YES', 'NO');
```

Although SQL Server Management Studio throws an error if you click "Design" on the view, you are still able to run `Selects` against it.

Comment: Post the full DDL statement you're executing to create the view. That statement on it's own doesn't create a `VIEW`, and seems pointless to have one with that expression.

Comment: Hi Tom, could you add the full CREATE VIEW statement with the IIF that you are working on?

Comment: I added the full statement

Comment: So why *do* you need a view which is just an expression, @TomelSafadi? A view is a precompiled `SELECT` statement that should be referencing some objects. A `VIEW` that is just an expression doesn't make sense.

Comment: I know what a View is and secondly this is for readability and I cannot post confidential information on here. @Larnu

Comment: We're not asking for data, @TomelSafadi we'll asking for the DDL; that doesn't contain any confidential information. Considering that the statement above doesn't create the problem you describe and as you admitted that the above isn't the SQL you're running it seems like the real problem is elsewhere, in SQL we haven't been shown.

Comment: I found out the problem. Gordon's code is right, however there is an issue with SSMS. If you create the view like Gordon did and the you click on design, SSMS throws an error as it doesn't seem to resolve "IIF". If you run a select against it, it still works. @Larnu

Comment: Please try it out in SSMS to see what I mean.

Comment: I never use the designer, @TomelSafadi, as it's really not a good interface; this question appears to actually prove that further. Editing any DDL by using T-SQL is by far always the better option.

Comment: That's true. I was just really confused why the desginer throws an error but I didn't think about that it could be a problem with the designer itself... Thanks for your input here:) @Larnu

Comment: I updated my question and the title. Maybe it's gonna help some other folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue is that you need to name the columns in a view.  Not naming the column gives a pretty clear error message:

> Msg 4511 Level 16 State 1 Line 2
>
> Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 1.

That is easily fixed with a name:

```
CREATE VIEW v as
    SELECT IIF(500<1000, 'YES', 'NO') as x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=704ef657c09cc59bf01efcbadbd12d15) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately, this still throws the same error...

Comment: Hello @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I added the full statement but the IIF doesn't seem to work inside a view... Is that correct?

Comment: @TomelSafadi . . . It works fine with a column name.  You can see the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Yes, it creates the view sucesfully but when you open the view it throws an error. Please try it out on a real Sql Server. I copied exactly the same code as what you have. @GordonLinoff

Comment: @TomelSafadi it works on a "real" SQL server too (at least on 2017 and 2019 and I very much think it'll work on 2008+). DBFiddle also uses a real SQL Server as it's back end. I suspect this is very much an XY problem.

Comment: IIF was introduced in SQL Server 2012.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The Fiddle shows me that it creates the View but it doesn't run a select against the View. I want to see it running a select on it... The information that the View was created succesfully doesn't help me. I am able to create the view but it doesn't work when I click on 'design' in SSMS... @Larnu

Comment: @TomelSafadi check the link again; Gordon updated it awhile ago.

Comment: Let me check if the Select works, but clicking on 'Design' in SSMS definetly throws an error for some reason @Larnu

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate your problem, it works OK for me on SQL Server 2017 (Express)

```
CREATE VIEW queryTest 
AS SELECT 
IIF(500 < 1000, 'YES', 'NO') as yn;

select * from querytest;
```

result:

```
yn
--
YES
```

Note that I added `as yn` to the view command as another poster suggested.